# Prevent KDE Kate 3.13 from auto-collapsing folders in Documents pane on File Open?

Tags: kde-plasma, kate

I've looked high and low through the settings, but I can't seem to figure out how to prevent KDE Kate 3.13 from auto-collapsing branches in the Documents pane when opening files. This is *really* annoying to me, since I then have to re-dig in to the collapsed file structures to figure out where the previous file I was working on is located.

Does anyone know where the secret sauce is on this one?

To reproduce this issue:

1. Have a Kate installation at or around version 3.13
2. Place the Documents pane in Tree view via Right Click->View Mode->Tree Mode
3. Open up several documents in different branches via File->Open.
4. Open up a file in a different branch than the currently exposed branches in the tree view.
5. Observe that the other branches in the Documents pane auto-collapse.

Workaround While Waiting For Fix:

1. Enable Console Tool and open Konsole interface (or use a regular Konsole instance)
2. execute "kate " to open the file without triggering the document collapse.

Comment: Can you explain the problem in more detail? "auto-collapsing branches in the Documents pane when opening files"?? I never experienced auto-collapsing directories in the document pane.

Comment: Sorry @MarcellFülöp -- I've added steps to reproduce to the OP.

Comment: In earlier versions of kate, that was controlled by `Settings->Configure Kate->Plugins->Symbol Viewer->Automatically expand nodes in tree mode` Good luck with the kde4 version...

Comment: Sadly, playing with the Symbol Viewer setting (or enabling/disabling it) has no effect on this issue. =o/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [bug report](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=332990) about it and we also have a [possible fix](https://git.reviewboard.kde.org/r/118312/). However, this fix was not yet applied. If all goes well, this is fixed for KDE SC 4.13.3.

Comment: Oh snap! Thank you, @dhaumann! I'd looked but not found a bug report, so assumed it must be user-error. Clearly, I need to work on my search-word guesses. Cheers!